# vba invalid identifier

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

For the following code Excel reports "Ungültiger Bezeichner" (Invalid identifiert). The line it complaines is `Select Case parts.Length`. It's complaining about `parts`. Any ideas?

```
Public Sub parseFileName(fName As String, ByRef art As String, ByRef objnr As String, ByRef phase As String, ByRef index As String, ByRef text As String, ByRef warning As Boolean)
    Dim parts() As String

    parts = Split(fName, ".")
    parts = Split(fName, parts(0))

    warning = False
    Select Case parts.Length
        Case Is < 5 ' not a valid filename, do nohting
            Return
        Case 5 ' old style file name
            art = part(0)
            objnr = part(1)
            text = part(2)
            index = part(4)
        Case 6 ' new stype file name
            art = part(0)
            phase = part(1)
            objnr = part(2)
            text = part(3)
            index = part(5)
        Case Is > 6 ' user used _ in text, do what we can and issue warning
            art = part(0)
            phase = part(1)
            objnr = part(2)
            text = part(3)
            index = part(5)
            warning = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine an array's length in VBA:

```
Dim arrLength as Integer

arrLength = UBound(parts) - LBound(parts) + 1
```